# Get the size of a map in Km generated by OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

I exported a part of my city using OpenstreetMap, so I have a .osm file that contains at the beginning of the file:

```
<bounds minlat="34.8743000" minlon="-1.3494000" maxlat="34.9035000" maxlon="-1.2926000"/>
```

I want to know the size of my map in Km. How do I do it?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/2983568) to compute the x and y sides/distances in km, then multiply x by y to get the area in km2.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I did not understand well, these two functions return at the end a single value which is named d, what are these x and y that you mentioned? more detail, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should have asked you first: what do you mean by "size of my map"? Is it the area (in km2)?

Comment: Yes, I would at the end a sentence like: The dimensions
of the map are X km × Y km (or in km2).

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this in an answer. These are the points you have as coordinates (boundaries) for your map:

```
                    ----------------- (max lat, max lon)
                    |               |
                    |               |
                    |               
                    |               y
                    |               
                    |               |
                    |               |
(min lat, min lon)  ------  x  ------ (min lat, max lon)
```

The function in [the answer I referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/2983568) provides the distance between 2 points. So to compute `x` you need the distance between point `(min lat, min lon)` and point `(min lat, max lon)`. You can compute y in a similar way.
For example point at bottom left is `(lat1, lon1)` and bottom right is `(lat2, lon2)` -> using the function you get `x`.
Same thread, [optimized code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623206/2983568).
Now if you just need this information once without actually programming anything, this is not so much a question for SO but you may use [this link](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml) to get the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but it's still not clear. The map I have has no shape (it is neither square nor rectangular), is your explanation valid for that too? Otherwise I have only one min lat, max lat, min lon and max lon! : 
<bounds minlat="34.8743000" minlon="-1.3494000" maxlat="34.9035000" maxlon="-1.2926000"/>

Comment: *The map I have has no shape (it is neither square nor rectangular), is your explanation valid for that too?* Of course not. If you only have the bounding box, there is no easy way to compute the area. You may check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/404476).